# OBS Studio interrupts xscreensaver

Tags: unix, youtube, x11

I'm trying to stream xscreensaver to youtube, like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjhC5Fpcx7k

When streaming is off, xscreensaver stays active. However, when OBS Studio is streaming, it interrupts the screensaver after a few seconds. The timing is random.

How can I monitor the triggers involved here? I believe that this is a bug, but where do I start fixing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a feature of OBS Studio, rather than a bug.

Ultimately, what is needed is disabling the function `os_inhibit_sleep_set_active` in `obs-studio/libobs/util/platform-nix.c` by commenting out its contents, and recompiling OBS ([according to the instructions](https://github.com/jp9000/obs-studio/wiki/Install-Instructions#linux-build-directions))